# R observation strs split - multiple value in columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe in R concerning houses. This is a small sample:

```
Address                              Type       Rent
Glasgow;Scotland                     House      1500
High Street;Edinburgh;Scotland      Apartment    1000
Dundee;Scotland                     Apartment    800
South Street;Dundee;Scotland        House       900
```

I would like to just pull out the last two instances of the Address column into a City and County column in my dataframe.

I have used mutate and strsplit to split this column by:

```
data<-mutate(dataframe, split_add = strsplit(dataframe$Address, ";")
```

I now have a new column in my dataframe which resembles the following:

```
split_add                             
c("Glasgow","Scotland")                     
c("High Street","Edinburgh","Scotland")      
c("Dundee","Scotland")                    
c("South Street","Dundee","Scotland")
```

How to I extract the last 2 instances of each of these vector observations into columns "City" and "County"?

I attempted:
    data<-mutate(data, city=split_add[-2] ))
thinking it would take the second instance from the end of the vectors- but this did not work.

Comment: Could you please use `dput()` to enable reproducible example?

Comment: You are looking for tail(x,2)..that is the code you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinking about another way of dealing with this problem.

1.Creating a dataframe with the split_add column data

```
c("Glasgow","Scotland")                      
c("High Street","Edinburgh","Scotland")      
c("Dundee","Scotland")                    
c("South Street","Dundee","Scotland")  

test_data <- data.frame(split_add <- c("Glasgow, Scotland",                     
                          "High Street, Edinburgh, Scotland",      
                          "Dundee, Scotland",                    
                          "South Street, Dundee, Scotland"),stringsAsFactors = F)
names(test_data) <- "address"
```

2.Use `separate()` from `tidyr` to split the column

```
library(tidyr)

new_test <- test_data %>% separate(address,c("c1","c2","c3"), sep=",")
```

3.Use `dplyr` and `ifelse()` to only reserve the last two columns

```
library(dplyr)
new_test %>% 
  mutate(city = ifelse(is.na(c3),c1,c2),county = ifelse(is.na(c3),c2,c3)) %>% 
  select(city,county)
```

The final data looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

using `tidyr::separate()` with the `fill = "left"` option is probably your best bet...

```
dataframe <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = "
Address                          Type       Rent
Glasgow;Scotland                 House      1500
'High Street;Edinburgh;Scotland' Apartment  1000
Dundee;Scotland                  Apartment  800
'South Street;Dundee;Scotland'   House      900
")

library(tidyr)

separate(dataframe, Address, into = c("Street", "City", "County"), 
         sep = ";", fill = "left")

#         Street      City   County      Type Rent
# 1         <NA>   Glasgow Scotland     House 1500
# 2  High Street Edinburgh Scotland Apartment 1000
# 3         <NA>    Dundee Scotland Apartment  800
# 4 South Street    Dundee Scotland     House  900
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you're using `dplyr`

`data <- mutate(dataframe, split_add = strsplit(Address, ';'), City = tail(split_add, 2)[1], Country = tail(split_add, 1))`

Comment: Downvote because this appears to be a guess. There is no [MCVE].